# Contact Form + jQuery validationengine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I created this contact form, inserting jQuery fadeLabel and validationEngine to beautify the form
the file index.php / .html (I have not yet figured out which of the two versions put it)
scripts are

index:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/backtop.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fadeLabel.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form .fadeLabel').fadeLabel();
});
</script>
<script src="/js/validationEngine-it.js"></script>
<script src="/js/validationEngine.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form_box").validationEngine({
ajaxSubmit: true,
ajaxSubmitFile: "contact.php",
ajaxSubmitMessage: "Thank you, We will contact you soon !",
success :  false,
    failure : function() {}
    })
    });
</script>
<script src="/js/contactform.js"></script>
```

however this is the part of the form's code

```
<p id="form_success" class="success hide"><strong>Grazie!</strong> Il tuo messaggio è  stato inviato con successo.</p>
    <form id="form_box">
    <fieldset>
    <p><label for="name">Nome*</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="validate[required] fadeLabel" value=""/></p>
    <p><label for="email">E-mail*</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] fadeLabel" value=""/></p>
    <p><label for="website">Sito web</label><input type="url" id="website" name="website" class="fadeLabel" value=""/></p>
    <p><label for="message">Messaggio*</label><textarea id="message" name="message" class="validate[required] fadeLabel" cols="30" rows="10" value=""></textarea></p>
    </fieldset>
    <p id="form_submit" class="submit"><button class="send">Invia</button> *Campi obbligatori</p>
    <p id="form_send" class="send hide">Invio in corso&hellip;</p>
    <p id="form_error" class="submit error hide"><button class="send">Invia</button> Si prega di correggere l'errore e re-inviarlo.</p>
    </form>
```

This is the contact.php where it receives the data and sends 2 emails (one for me with the data and a thank you to those who contacted me)
contact.php:

```
<?php
//include variables
$my_email = "adrygese@gmail.com";
$my_site = "adrianogenovese.com";

    session_start();

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//beginning to email me
$to  = $my_email;
$sbj = "Richiesta Informazioni - $my_site";
$msg = "
<html>
...
//the body of the email to me
...
</html>
";

$from      = $email;
$headers   = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers  .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers  .= "From: $from";

mail($to,$sbj,$msg,$headers); //email sent to me

//beginning of the email recipient
$toClient  = $email;
$msgClient = "
<html>
...
//the body of the email recipient
...
</html>
";
$fromClient     = $my_email;
$sbjClient      = "Grazie $name per aver contattato $my_site ";
$headersClient  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headersClient .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headersClient .= "From: $fromClient";

mail($toClient,$sbjClient,$msgClient,$headersClient); //mail inviata al cliente

//order confirmation email

//Reset error

session_destroy();

exit;

?>
```

this is the contact form jscript
contactform.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".send").click(function(){

$("#form_send").removeClass('hide');
$("#form_submit").addClass('hide');
$("#form_error").addClass('hide');

var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var website = $("#website").val();
var message = $("#message").val();

if (name == "" || email == "" )  {
    $("#form_send").addClass('hide');
    $("#form_error").removeClass('hide');
}

else {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contatti/contact.php",

    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email  + "&message=" + message + "&website=" + website,
    dataType: "html",

    success: function(msg) {
        $("#form_send").addClass('hide').delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
        $("#form_success").removeClass('hide');
        $("#form_box").addClass('hide').slideUp(2000).fadeOut();
    },

    error: function() {

    alert("An unexpected error occurred..."); 
    }   

    });

}

}); //end form

});//end Dom
```

The jQuery seem to work very well, I wanted to make sure that the page is not of the form updated or go to another page (the only thing that works for now)
compensation reflected in the following problems:

1. I always leave the alert of contactform.js
2. Does not send any mail, it to me to recipient
3. I can not do the work properly. delay () .fadeOut / fadeIn and. SlideUp (). FadeOut ()
   so that the sending of this email appears for 3 seconds "$ (" # form_send "). addClass ('hide')" before you do anything else then the form disappears up using some second type slideUp "$ (" # form_box "). addClass ('hide')" by displaying just the "$ (" # form_success "). removeClass ('hide')"
4. in the address bar also appears the form data (e.g. ../index.php?name=test&email=example%40mail.com&website=&message=helloworld)

Comment: In order to receive an answer I seriously suggest narrowing your question down. Instead of your whole collection of controllers/views, just post the section that isn't providing the desired result. Good luck!

Comment: Hello Wilde,
thank you very much for your answer, kindly explain to you better than I did not understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should specify `action` and `method` for your form tag:

```
<form id="form_box" method="post" action="contatti/contact.php">
```

Secondly, you are never stopping the form from submitting on failure. You need to return `false` in your javascript from preventing from submitting if you want to handle the form on the client side:

```
if (name == "" || email == "" )  {
    $("#form_send").addClass('hide');
    $("#form_error").removeClass('hide');
    return false;
}
```

In your `$.ajax()` submission `data` is set incorrectly. Do the following:

```
data: $('#form_box').serialize()
```

This is a start.

Comment: Hello 3dgoo,
Meanwhile, thanks for the answer.
With the changes you suggested I get e-mails but
- The jQuery validationEngine no longer works
- When I hit the send button is always the pop-up of Alert
- I am redirected to the page (...contact/contact.php) with blank page

Comment: @BigMad - It is impossible to help you with a problem that I can't see. Share a running version of your code with the problem if you want me to help.

Comment: The original contact form you can find on [this page](http://www.adrianogenovese.com/contatti/)
I added your previous edits.